# google sites on a private cloud

Tags: drupal, google

Can google sites/apps be installed on your own infrastructure say the way Drupal or Wordpress could?

I can't seem to find resources pointing me towards the way to do this. Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put: No .

Google sites/apps have tiers of 'security'/'privacy' (Government, education, business); but nothing you can put on your own hosts.

Comment: Thanks - that is what I thought - I was led to believe that Google might have an onsite installable option - but I came accross nothing online to support that assumption. This has been validating - appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

No, in short. A lot of the marketing towards it is geared around the fact that it will be a decentralised, outsourced, managed system. Locally hosting would pretty much defeat the point.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options out there to host your own services similar to what Google offers, either on a private cloud, or more traditionally.

[Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/products/zimbra-open-source.html) is one example, and there are plenty of others.